# How to get Login Component as default route in ABP Angular architecture

Tags: angular, authentication, components, abp

I am using asp .net core and Angular ABP architecture . When I navigate to `http://localhost:4200`/ I got home page as it is in default route as follows

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.account').then(m => m.AccountModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'identity',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.identity').then(m => m.IdentityModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'tenant-management',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@abp/ng.tenant-management').then(m => m.TenantManagementModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'setting-management',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@abp/ng.setting-management').then(m => m.SettingManagementModule.forLazy()),
  },
];
```

I need login page as my default routing . But I cant understand how its routing works when I click login button it redirect to the another port like `https://localhost:44325/Account/Login?`

I want to change the default route from home to login page .

Answer (score 1):

See your code:

```
{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
},
```

The home module is the default. path : ''

If your login page is in this module use the login component default, otherwise first make the module default which contains the login component and then change the default component in that module

seems your login component is in the AccountModule

```
{
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.account').then(m => m.AccountModule.forLazy()),
},
```

If that is true, then make it first as default module and then login to default component, and you are done

Answer (score 0):

First, change your home path like this:

```js
{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
}
```

Then change your account module as default path:

```js
{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.account').then(m => m.AccountModule.forLazy()),
}
```

And inside your account-routing-module add this, but check the path's name of your login component.

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: accountComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }]
}];
```